# Is there a way to scroll div B when div A is scrolled with momentum?

Tags: javascript, ipad, plugins, jquery-plugins, scroll

I have an iPad web application and I have 2 lists with overflow scroll. When list A is scrolled down I also want list B to be scrolled. I also want any momentum on list A also to apply on list B? Is this possible, or is there any known plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using native events you can only sync the final, after scroll, position. 
If you really need to sync the momentum - custom scrolling lib need to be used. There are lot of them - touch-scroll, iScroll, Scrollability.